# Android array out of bounds and SQL null pointer exception

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, random, nullpointerexception

So I am building this Android simulation game and I have some SQL and array problems.

While trying to put some values from a random position in an array, I get an array-out-of-bounds error on these lines:

```
int max = 10;
int min = 0;
Random r = new Random();
int num = r.nextInt(max-min) + min;
if (west_teams[num].equals(teams[0]) ||
    west_teams[num].equals(teams[1]) ||
    west_teams[num].equals(teams[2]) ||
    west_teams[num].equals(teams[3]) ||
    west_teams[num].equals(teams[4]) ||
    west_teams[num].equals(teams[5]) ||
    west_teams[num].equals(teams[6]) ||
    west_teams[num].equals(teams[7])
   )
```

In the SQLite problem, I get a Java null pointer exception error on these lines:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(TEAM, team);
cv.put(LOCATION, Location);
cv.put(PLAYER, Player);
cv.put(CRANGE, cRange);
cv.put(MRANGE, mRange);
cv.put(TRANGE, tRange);
cv.put(FREETHROW, Freethrow);
cv.put(PASS, Pass);
cv.put(DEF_REBOUND, Def_rebound);
cv.put(OFF_REBOUND, Off_rebound);
cv.put(BLOCK, Block);
cv.put(STEAL, Steal);
cv.put(STAMINA, Stamina);
return ourDatabase.insert(PLAYERS_TABLE, null, cv);
```

Here is my complete code:

#### Randomize class:

```
package ent.com;

import java.util.Random;
import android.content.Context;

public class RandPlayers {
    protected Context context;

    public void fetch_players(String location, String savename){
        this.context = context;
        String[] first_names = new String[] {"John", "Jonathan", "James", "Drew", "Tim", "Tony", "Anthony", "Andrew", "Brandon", "Michael", "Mike", "Devin", "Marcus", "George", "Noah", "Martin", "Kevin", "Quentin", "Boris", "Stepehn"};
        String[] last_names = new String[] {"Parker", "Robinson", "Jackson", "Charles", "Powell", "Wilkerson", "Mitchell", "Russel", "Flint", "Griffin", "Simpson", "Springfield", "Booker", "Wilks", "Flanders", "Levingston", "Fernandez", "Rodriguez", "Evans", "Smith"};
        String[] west_teams = new String[] {"Seattle Ice", "Las Vegas Dragons", "Salt Lake Vampires", "Vancouver Wildfire", "Olympia Peninsulas", "San Diego Rings", "San Francisco Flyers", "Austin Fortress", "Idaho Eagles"};
        String[] east_teams = new String[] {"Jackson Giants", "Tampa Wildbears", "Nashville Monarchs", "Springfield Defenders", "Minneapolis Ballers", "Ottawa Moose", "Columbus Natives", "Cincinnati Lightning", "Baltimore Invaders", "Montreal Fishers"};

        String[] teams = new String[] {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};

        String[] players = new String[] {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};

        SetSql PlayerObject =  new SetSql(this.context);

        int i;
        int y;

        if(location.equals("w")){
            teams[7] = savename;
            for(i = 0; i<7; i++){
                int max = 10;
                int min = 0;
                Random r = new Random();
                int num =min + r.nextInt(max-min);
                if(west_teams[num].equals(teams[0]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[1]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[2]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[3]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[4]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[5]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[6]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[7]))
                {
                    i--;
                }
                else{
                    teams[i] = west_teams[num];
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            for(i = 0; i<8; i++){
                int max = 10;
                int min = 0;
                Random r = new Random();
                int num = r.nextInt(max-min) + min;
                if(west_teams[num].equals(teams[0]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[1]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[2]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[3]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[4]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[5]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[6]) ||
                   west_teams[num].equals(teams[7]))
                {
                    i--;
                }
                else{
                    teams[i] = west_teams[num];
                }
            }
        }
        if(location.equals("e")){
            for(y = 8; y<15; y++){
                teams[15] = savename;
                int max = 10;
                int min = 0;
                Random r = new Random();
                int num = r.nextInt(max-min) + min;
                if(east_teams[num].equals(teams[8])  ||
                   east_teams[num].equals(teams[9])  ||
                   east_teams[num].equals(teams[10]) ||
                   east_teams[num].equals(teams[11]) ||
                   east_teams[num].equals(teams[12]) ||
                   east_teams[num].equals(teams[13]) ||
                   east_teams[num].equals(teams[14]) ||
                   east_teams[num].equals(teams[15]))
                {
                    y--;
                }
                else{
                    teams[y] = west_teams[num];
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            for(y = 8; y<16; y++){
                int max = 10;
                int min = 0;
                Random r = new Random();
                int num = r.nextInt(max-min) + min;
                if(east_teams[num].equals(teams[8])||east_teams[num].equals(teams[9])||east_teams[num].equals(teams[10])||east_teams[num].equals(teams[11])||east_teams[num].equals(teams[12])||east_teams[num].equals(teams[13])||east_teams[num].equals(teams[14])||east_teams[num].equals(teams[15]))
                {
                    y--;
                }
                else{
                    teams[y] = west_teams[num];
                }
            }
        }

        for(int w=0; w<16; w++){
            int min = 0;
            int max = 20;
            int smin = 1;
            int smax = 21;
            Random names = new Random();
            int fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            int snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            int cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            int mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            int tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            int Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            int Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            int Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            int Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            int Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            int Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            int Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[0], "w", players[0], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[1], "w", players[1], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[2], "w", players[2], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[3], "w", players[3], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[4], "w", players[4], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[5], "w", players[5], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[6], "w", players[6], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[7], "w", players[7], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[8], "w", players[8], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[9], "w", players[9], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[10], "w", players[10], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[11], "w", players[11], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[12], "w", players[12], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[13], "w", players[13], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[14], "w", players[14], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);

            fnum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            snum = names.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            players[0] = first_names[fnum] + " " + last_names[snum];
            cRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            mRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            tRange = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Freethrow = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Pass = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Def_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Off_rebound = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Block = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Steal = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            Stamina = names.nextInt(smax-smin)+smin;
            PlayerObject.createPlayerEntry(teams[15], "w", players[15], cRange, mRange, tRange, Freethrow, Pass, Def_rebound, Off_rebound, Block, Steal, Stamina);
        }
    }
}
```

#### SQLite setup page:

```
package ent.com;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SetSql{
    String saveExtra=null;

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_SAVE = "save_name";
    public static final String KEY_STADIUM = "stadium_size";
    public static final String KEY_FINANCE = "total_money";

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = null;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "save_data";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String PLAYERS_TABLE = "player_data";

    public static final String ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String TEAM = "team";
    public static final String LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String PLAYER = "player_name";
    public static final String CRANGE = "close_range";
    public static final String MRANGE = "mid_range";
    public static final String TRANGE = "three_range";
    public static final String FREETHROW = "free_throw";
    public static final String PASS = "pass";
    public static final String DEF_REBOUND = "def_rebound";
    public static final String OFF_REBOUND = "off_rebound";
    public static final String BLOCK = "block";
    public static final String STEAL = "steal";
    public static final String STAMINA = "stamina";

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //userdata db
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_SAVE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_STADIUM + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_FINANCE + " DOUBLE NOT NULL);");

            //players data db
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + PLAYERS_TABLE + " (" +
                    ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    TEAM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    PLAYER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    CRANGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    MRANGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    TRANGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    FREETHROW + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    PASS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    DEF_REBOUND + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    OFF_REBOUND + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    BLOCK + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    STEAL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    STAMINA + " INTEGER NOT NULL);");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PLAYERS_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public SetSql(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public SetSql open(){
        ourHelper =  new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public void start(String num){
        saveExtra = num;
        DATABASE_NAME = saveExtra;
    }

    public long createEntry(String value, int seats, int money, String players) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_SAVE, value);
        cv.put(KEY_STADIUM, seats);
        cv.put(KEY_FINANCE, money);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String getdata() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_SAVE, KEY_STADIUM, KEY_FINANCE};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iSave = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SAVE);
        int iSeats = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STADIUM);
        int iMoney = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FINANCE);

        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + "-" + c.getString(iSave) + "-" + c.getString(iSeats) + "-" + c.getString(iMoney) + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public long createPlayerEntry(String team, String Location, String Player, int cRange, int mRange, int tRange, int Freethrow, int Pass, int Def_rebound, int Off_rebound, int Block, int Steal, int Stamina) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TEAM, team);
        cv.put(LOCATION, Location);
        cv.put(PLAYER, Player);
        cv.put(CRANGE, cRange);
        cv.put(MRANGE, mRange);
        cv.put(TRANGE, tRange);
        cv.put(FREETHROW, Freethrow);
        cv.put(PASS, Pass);
        cv.put(DEF_REBOUND, Def_rebound);
        cv.put(OFF_REBOUND, Off_rebound);
        cv.put(BLOCK, Block);
        cv.put(STEAL, Steal);
        cv.put(STAMINA, Stamina);
        return ourDatabase.insert(PLAYERS_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String getplayerdata() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{ROWID, TEAM, LOCATION, PLAYER, CRANGE, MRANGE, TRANGE, FREETHROW, PASS, DEF_REBOUND, OFF_REBOUND, BLOCK, STEAL, STAMINA};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(PLAYERS_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(ROWID);
        int iTeam = c.getColumnIndex(TEAM);
        int iLocation = c.getColumnIndex(LOCATION);
        int iPlayer = c.getColumnIndex(PLAYER);
        int iCrange = c.getColumnIndex(CRANGE);
        int iMrange = c.getColumnIndex(MRANGE);
        int iTrange = c.getColumnIndex(TRANGE);
        int iFreethrow = c.getColumnIndex(FREETHROW);
        int iPass = c.getColumnIndex(PASS);
        int iDef_rebound = c.getColumnIndex(DEF_REBOUND);
        int iOff_rebound = c.getColumnIndex(OFF_REBOUND);
        int iBlock = c.getColumnIndex(BLOCK);
        int iSteal = c.getColumnIndex(STEAL);
        int iStamina = c.getColumnIndex(STAMINA);

        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + "-" + c.getString(iTeam) + "-" + c.getString(iLocation) + "-" + c.getString(iPlayer) + "-" + c.getString(iCrange) + "-" + c.getString(iMrange) + "-" +c.getString(iTrange) + "-" +c.getString(iFreethrow) + "-" +c.getString(iPass) + "-" +c.getString(iDef_rebound) + "-" +c.getString(iOff_rebound) + "-" +c.getString(iBlock) + "-" +c.getString(iSteal) + "-" +c.getString(iStamina) + "-" +"\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: specify exactly where you get your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I count west_teams as having 9 members, which will be indexed 0 to 8. But your random number could be 9, giving you the out of bounds error.